# consuming wsdl in spring mvc

Tags: web-services, spring-mvc

My IDE set up is

- Eclipse Indigo
- Spring IDE for indigo
- Spring STS for indigo
- maven integration for eclipse
- maven integration for eclipse wtp

  1. Created a sample spring mvc project and performed maven clean and maven build.

I have a wsdl from client which i have included in a project that uses `cxf-wsdl2java` to generate the proxy code. Not sure if this is the right way to approach this. The web service is on 'axis'

Looking for tutorial on how to consume the wsdl and make the method calls in spring mvc project using maven. also is cxf the right way to approach this? particularly the wsdl2java approach

Answer (score 1):

It is usually a good practice to use the wsdl2java with maven (except that I would have not copied the wsdl inside the resources, but I would have kept it on the distant server). As this if the wsdl change, you will ne notified directly with your build. 
For your client, just configure your endpoint. see the 'Configuring a Spring Client' doc from cxf : http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html

Comment: I used `cxf-codegen-plugin` to generate the package in a separate project. I assume this is not right way to do it? I should use the maven and append it to have the jax-ws stuff in it and then build up from there? If i do it as per the info in your posting, how would I invoke the webservice in my client code?

Comment: You can have your generated files wherever you want (as long as they are seen on your projects/modules).

Comment: In the documentation, you can create a jaxws client. Just (auto)wire it as an usual service in Spring.

Comment: sorry, should have mentioned that this is my first spring based project? would appreciate any guidance to links that show how to auto wire

Comment: So read Spring framework documentation before starting playing with cxf http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the Spring Web Service project found here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/

Ihere is a tutorial (located here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html) on their website which goes through both creating a contract first web service, as well as a consumer of that web service.

Hope this helps!